# handling oracle's ROWID in apache hive

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hive, hiveql, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm converting oracle sql queries to hiveql; how to convert queries with ROWID in oracle to hive.

Example:

```
select ROWID,
       name,
       country
from   table1
where  date = to_date('10/11/2015','mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Comment: `ROWID` is an Oracle extension allowing to *efficiently* identify a row. By its distributed nature, with Hive, it is hard to achieve generate a globally unique identifier for each row. And it wouldn't be very efficient, I think. Don't you have any primary or unique key in your record that could be used instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive doesn't have the feature of unique identifier of each row (rowid). But if you don't have any primary key or unique key values, you can use the analytical function row_number.

Answer (score 0):

Hivemall provides `rowid()` function that generates unique identifier for each row. The identifier is formatted as `${task_id}-${sequence_number}`.

https://github.com/myui/hivemall/wiki/Adding-rowid-for-each-row